# Validate complex object on GET request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, validation

I'm trying to apply input validation on a complex parameter of a get request.
What I have:

```
data class FilterDTO (

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    val id: Long? = null,

    @NotNull
    val code: String? = null
)
```

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
class FooController {

    @GetMapping
    fun get(
        @Valid filter: FilterDTO,
        @Valid @NotNull @RequestParam("bar") bar: String?
    ) {
      // ...
    }

}
```

The above endpoint validates correctly the `@NotNull` on the `bar` parameter but it seems to ignore the validation on the complex `FilterDTO` object.

I have tried:

- Adding `@Valid` on `FilterDTO`'s properties (even with Kotlin's `@field:` and `@get:`)
- Adding `@Validated` (??) on the `FilterDTO` whole class

Couldn't make it work.

Is it possible to have a complex get parameter validated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. For anyone getting here, I should be annotating with `@field:` the validations I want. So simply changing my DTO to this worked:

```
data class FilterDTO (

    @field:NotNull
    val id: Long? = null,

    @field:NotNull
    val code: String? = null
)
```